# Pass Python array to javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html

I'm new to HTML/javascript.  I'm running a local server, with an html/javascript file and a separate python script.

Question: **How do I pass a python array to javascript variable?**

Work so far: 
I've written the array to file `data.txt`:

```
1  32.1
2  10.0
```

but I could put it in JSON format if it's easier.

**Here's my progress so far**:

```
var x_pos = [];
jQuery.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/data/data.txt',function(data){

// ??? Code here ???

});

console.log(x_pos[0])
```

Note: if there is a much simpler way to do this, I'm open to suggestion.  Thanks.

Comment: you could split at every newline, and then again at the space between the number and the value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var x_array = [];    
var y_array = [];     

jQuery.get('http://localhost/test/data.txt',function(data){
    var lines = data.split(/\r\n|\n/g);
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        line = lines[i].split(/\s+/g);
        x_array.push(line[0]);
        y_array.push(line[1]);
    }
    console.log(x_array);
    console.log(y_array);
});
```

Comment: What if OP has `\r\n` as carriage returns?

Comment: Updated to handle \r\n case and one or more spaces between the two values in every line of text file.

Comment: Yes, this is also what I would do to parse the file `split('\n')` and line `split('\s+')`

Comment: @MazzCris Thanks , this works pretty well...except that `console.log(x_array)` returns `undefined` when outside of the `jQuery.get(...)` call.  Any suggestions?  I thought I had a handle on scope :/

Comment: @anon0909 jQuery.get() is asynchronous (being a shorthand Ajax function as explained here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get ). Anyway I think you should get an empty array in that case (as it was initialized), not `undefined`

Comment: @MazzCris I see - I was just looking into asynchronous calls/callback functions.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use JSON instead. Then you can just parse it as

```
jQuery.get('http://localhost/data.txt', function(data) {
  var xy = JSON.parse(data);
});
```

and use as

```
alert(xy['1']); // or xy.propertyname if it is not-numeric
```

Your data structure would be like

```
{
  "1": 32.1,
  "2": 0
}
```

Comment: It's a text file, how can you use json.parse on something that isn't in json format?

Comment: @Daniel_L **THIS** is a better solution.

Comment: The OP specifies that if there's a better way to handle the parsing by changing the format and/or extension of the text file, we should suggest it, So I agree that putting the text in json format would simplify the parsing tremendously and give the OP the simplest way to get the data into variables.

Comment: @Daniel_L **"If there's an easier way to get text into numerical variables, feel free to suggest that; I'm looking for the simplest, canonical solution to this problem. Thanks!"**

Comment: @brso05 I didn't see that initially. I have adjusted my votes accordingly. Without spamming the comments in bold

Comment: @anon0909 JSON is very comfortable to use, it is easy to read, it is supported by nearly every programming language which makes it one of the best ways to communicate between client and server.

Comment: @anon0909 I assume jQuery automatically understands that the file format is JSON and parses it for you, so the `data` already has everything you need. Could you try to replace this line `var xy = JSON.parse(data);` with just `var xy = data;`?

Answer (score 2):

Just create a json structure for this and do a `JSON.parse(data)` after.

Here is your structure:

`{x: [1,2,3,4], y:[32.1,10.0,76.3]}`

Answer (score 1):

One of the solutions is use split. It splits the string.

```
    var newData = [];
    data = data.split('\n');
    data.forEach(function(entry){
      entry = entry.split(' ');
      newData.push({
        x : entry[0],
        y : entry[1]
      });
    });
    console.log(newData);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use regular expressions to parse the text file. You cannot just use `JSON.parse()` on a string that isn't in json format.

http://plnkr.co/edit/39aBGgwvNI7Lem6eiefu?p=preview

```
$.get("http://localhost/data.txt", parse);

function parse(str) {
    var lineBreak = /\r\n/g;
    var space = /\s/g;
    var tmp = str.split(lineBreak).map(function(l) {
        var split = l.split(space);
        return { key: split[0], val: split[1]  };
    });
    var data = JSON.stringify(tmp, null, 2);
    $("#data").text(data);
}
```